# Representing a logarithmic graph as a percentage by tending to 100

Tags: calculus, logarithms

Preface: I am currently in college in my first year of maths, so some more intricate explanations may not be available to me.

The situation I am modelling is that of an engineer repairing a machine, the more work he does, the less of a result it has overall, a classic diminishing returns problem. I would like to represent the machines efficiency (how repaired it is) as a percentage or a number from one to one hundred.

A logarithmic function $r=\ln(w+1)$ can be used to describe the diminishing returns relationship between work done ($w$, in hours) and result ($r$). My problem lies in the fact that result tends to infinity, where I would prefer it tends to 100: $\lim\limits_{w\to \infty} r=\ln(w+1)=100$

In my understanding of maths, to represent a number from 1 to n as a percentage, you would do $\frac{number}{n}*100$, but obviously I cannot simply divide by infinity.
How could I modify this function so that it tends to 100 instead of infinity?

Comment: Please show the kind of curve that you would like. There are too many options.

Comment: I would like a curve, with decreasing gradient to tend to 100 (or n), as x tends to infinity. I have no idea how to achieve this however

Comment: Thank you @MattiP. , Ill mark you correct if you post an answer

Comment: This description is insufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like
$$
r(w) = 100 \left(1-\frac{a}{w-a} \right)
$$
and tweak the value of the parameter $a$ to your liking, for example $a=100$.